# g++ and clang++ different behaviour with SFINAE and SFINAE failure

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, sfinae, clang++

A couple of questions for C++11 experts.

I'm fighting with SFINAE and I came across a strange case in which g++ (4.9.2), and clang++ (3.5.0) behave differently.

I have prepared the following sample code. I'm sorry but I'm unable to do it significantly more concise.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename X>
class foo
 {
   private:
      template <typename R>
         using enableIfIsInt
         = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<X, int>::value, R>::type;

   public:
      foo ()
       { }

      template <typename R = void>
         enableIfIsInt<R> bar ()
          { std::cout << "bar: is int\n"; }

      void bar ()
       {
         std::cout << "bar: isn't int; is [" << typeid(X).name() << "]{"
            << typeid(enableIfIsInt<void>).name() << "}\n";
       }
 };


int main ()
 {
   foo<long>  fl;
   foo<int>  fi;

   fl.bar();
   fi.bar();

   return 0;
 }
```

My idea was to create a template `foo<X>` class that (via SFINAE) can define a method in one or in another way depending on the `X` template argument.

The program compile well with g++ 4.9.2 but clang++ 3.5.0 give the following error

```
test.cpp:13:36: error: no type named 'type' in
      'std::__1::enable_if<false, void>'; 'enable_if' cannot be used to disable
      this declaration
         = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<X, int>::value, R>::type;
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:26:23: note: in instantiation of template type
      alias 'enableIfIsInt' requested here
            << typeid(enableIfIsInt<void>).name() << "}\n";
                      ^
test.cpp:36:7: note: in instantiation of member function
      'foo<long>::bar' requested here
   fl.bar();
      ^
1 error generated.
```

I suppose that is right clang++ but my first question to C++11 experts is: who right? g++ or clang++?

About the g++ produced program output, it's the following

```
bar: isn't int; is [i]{v}
```

so g++ seems to ignore the `fl.bar();` instruction.

Now a little change: i modify the second version of `foo<X>::bar()` in this way

```
  void bar ()
   { std::cout << "bar: isn't int; is [" << typeid(X).name() << "]\n"; }
```

deleting the `std::enable_if` inside the function abomination. Now both g++ and clang++ are compiling without problems and the output, for both compiled versions of the program, is

```
bar: isn't int; is [l]
bar: isn't int; is [i]
```

So, my second question is: what I'm doing wrong? Why, in the `int` case, I don't obtain the `"is int"` version of `foo<X>::bar()`?

Be patient with me if I'm doing some foolish: I'm trying to learn C++11.

And sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Have you tried this with a more recent clang version (like 3.8) and a more recent gcc (like 5.3)? Might be instructive...

Comment: Mostly minimized repro: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/713fbbbca7e8b8c5. I blame caching.

Comment: Reported as https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=70642

Comment: @T.C. Wow, I totally forgot about the "wtf is gcc doing?" part of the question. Great catch there.

Comment: @ Jesper Juhl - No sorry. Are the latest compilers I have available at the time.

Comment: @ T.C. - I never thought to use SFINAE to delete a method. Nice. And nice minimized example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

clang's error isn't coming from the substitution failure. It's coming from here:

```
  void bar ()
   {
     std::cout << "bar: isn't int; is [" << typeid(X).name() << "]{"
        << typeid(enableIfIsInt<void>).name() << "}\n"; // <==
   }
```

`enableIfIsInt<void>` isn't in the immediate context, that's a hard failure for `X` is not `int`. You simply can't use that expression in that context.

Once you remove that - the non-template `bar()` is always called. That's because both functions are equivalent matches and non-templates are preferred to templates in overload resolution.

So the real solution is to use tag-dispatching:

```
void bar() { bar(std::is_same<X, int>{}); }

void bar(std::true_type ) {
    std::cout << "bar: is int\n";
}

void bar(std::false_type ) {
    std::cout << "bar: isn't int; is [" << typeid(X).name() << "]\n";
}
```

with which both compilers happily yield:

```
bar: isn't int; is [l]
bar: is int
```

Comment: what I had not focused was that non-templates are preferred to templates in overload resolution; thanks.